# Getting icon package path in String java

Tags: java, swing, resources, icons, embedded-resource

I have project in which i have made package for icons..e.g com.example.icon and com.example.classes....now i want to set a String path variable to set path like this .../src/com/example/ui, and after that i specify the icon name with it and access icon..problem is i want to set it dynamically so that my jar file will not have problems in different systems..how to set path variable i am not able to figure out..thank you

I have saw `File.getResource("some file name")` but i do't want to set any file name at start..
and i am using net beans

**EDIT**

now i am using this code..

```
  URL url = Main.class.getResource("PATH"); 
  String path = url.toString();
  .......
  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(path+"/add_icon.png");
```

but it not showing icons and showing Depericated Api error for "sun.tools.jar.main" and i checked system out path value it was valid..
....?

Comment: Try `String path =  "/com/example/ui";  ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource(path+"/add_icon.png"));`

Answer (score 4):

Try to use

```
getClass().getResource("com/example/ui/imageFile");
```

Comment: URL url = Main.Class.getClass().getResource("/com/idoccsmain/icons/");
String path = rul.toString();
......
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(path+"/add_icon.png");

I am using it like this but it is showing me some deprecated api "sun.tools.jar.main" and my icons are not loaded yet..

Comment: Each image should be loaded as
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(Main.Class.getClass().getResource("/com/idoccsmain/icons/"+"add_icon.png");

Comment: Now i am trying it as you mentioned...when i run it via IDE it is getting icons...but when i run it after making jar file it is not showing file...?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do it. Either you use command Line arguments

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String path = args[0];
}
```

or properties

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load("Some Properties file in a fixed location");

String path = props.getProperty("path");
```

or system properties (Invoking with a -Dpath option)

```
String path = System.getProperty("path");
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, you could use the ClassLoader to get the InputStream and read a file.

```
 fis = YourClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(FILE);
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using NetBeans IDE then you can use **"jXImagePanel"** for displaying the image the code for setting the image to jXImagePanel is :

`jXImagePanel2.setImage(getImage("icons/yourimage.jpg"));`

Comment: That is not a problem...but my problem is to get path till the "icons package".